# Delete locked Access database

Tags: locking, ms-access-2010

I have an Access database (.accdb) file that must be replaced with a backup copy.  Unfortunately, the file is locked with an (.laccdb) and I cannot rename or remove either file.

I don't exactly know who is locking the file and it could be contractors across the globe.  So I can't just ask everyone to disconnect.

How can I unlock, remove, or rename the locked .accdb file?

Answer (score 6):

On the machine hosting the database file, open the Computer Management applet in Windows, expand

System Tools > Shared Folders > Open Files

and see if the .accdb and .laccdb files are listed. If so, try closing them either by right-clicking or by selecting the file and choosing "Close Open File" under "More Actions".

I just tried that under Windows 8.1 and it enabled me to delete a local database file that was currently opened by another machine.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the file and select 'Restore Previous Version.' I just clicked on one that was from the week prior and then the file disappeared after a few seconds.